# Access Violation error using IInterfaceList Delphi XE3

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I have encountered an access violation error [Access violation at address 5005F6E in module 'rtl170'. Read of address 0000000A] using the IInterfaceList.
My code looks something like this:

```
if  not Assigned(FoRoutingCodes) then Exit;
for i := 0 to FoRoutingCodes.nCount - 1 do
begin
  ...
end;
```

the declaration of FoRoutingCodes is:

```
FoRoutingCodes : IRoutingCodeList;
```

and the definition of IRoutingCodeList

```
IRoutingCodeList = interface
  function GetCount: Integer;
    ...
  property nCount: Integer read GetCount;
end;
```

the implementation of nCount property is:

```
function TRoutingCodeList.GetCount: Integer;
begin
  Result := 0;
  if Assigned(FoItems) then
    Result := FoItems.Count; // here i get the access violation error
end;
```

where TRoutingCodeList is the implementation of IRoutingCodeList and FoItems is declared as:

```
FoItems: IInterfaceList;
```

I have fixed this using

```
FoItems: TList<IRoutingCode>;
```

instead of

```
FoItems: IInterfaceList;
```

I am new to delphi, can anyone help me understand what was wrong with previous approach.
I don't know if this is relevant because there are many other changes is our product, but this issue appeared only after we moved from Delphi XE to Delphi XE3.

Thanks in advance.

**Update: in response to Uwe Raabe**

I have changed FoItems initialisation from

```
constructor TRoutingCodeList.Create;
begin
  FoItems := TInterfaceList.Create;
end;
```

to

```
constructor TRoutingCodeList.Create;
begin
  FoItems := TList<IRoutingCode>.Create;
end;
```

Comment: you have a nil dereference. you almost certainly try to do something like `x := TSomeClass(nil).SomeMember`. Think which pointer passed to RTL could be zero

Comment: I don't cast back from the interface to some class nowhere in my code... or maybe I misunderstood what you're trying to say?

Comment: Interfaced objects in Delphi implement a specific memory model of Automatic Reference Counting. You have to accommodate for this in a special way, which may be implemented or not implemented in "TList<T>". Set some logging in object destructors and most probably you would see objects unexpectedly destroyed in the moment you pass them to the list or soon after. Base your list on a specific interface-aware list http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Classes.TInterfaceList

Comment: Can you show how you initialize FoItems either way?

Comment: Pavel - use back-ticks to highlight the sources. When you enter new comment - there is "help" link to the right. /// This should be correct creation... If you really want it - then set "use debug DCUs" in project options, set breakpoint in `TInterfaceList` destructor and then see the stack trace - where and why it is destroyed. May be even bug in compiler or RTL. // and if you use `iInterfaceList` type try to never use `TInterfaceList` - such mixes lead to troubles, either one or another wat. BTW, how to you delete it in your destructor ? Also - try to remove `If Assigned(FoItems)` and test

Comment: "I don't cast back from the interface to some class" the program does. And somehow almost certainly ends with nil pointer. You may just switch to `TList<T>` or `TInterfaceLdit` or due to curiosity try to debug an issue with `iInterfaceList`. May it be that `Assigned(intf)` clears it instead ? or whatever else. Also Win32 and Win64 codes might differ. Also did you installed all XE3 updates ?

Comment: Please show an SSCCE. Piecing together fragments is pointless. Make an SSCCE that is as small as possible.

Comment: Or he keeps object references to the objects of the elements of the list, and it is those that are/become nil, not the Iinterfacelist? Anyway, indeed, after a few times back and forth, it becomes time for a minimal compilable example.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort if to take his words at face value, then in his XE3 copy  `if Assigned(VarInterface)` causes the var decrement refcounter and became nil. Something unholy happens... Maybe it is IDE debugger who manages to interfere with refcounted class memebers ?

Comment: I don't use `if Assigned(FoItems) then` in my code, I have checked that this is true only on debug in inspector window, so this isn't the problem here. @DavidHeffernan I will try to make an SSCCE when I get home, because in the real scenario at my work this project is quite big, and I can't reproduce this in a small code example right now.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce this in a small code example, why would we be able to? You've asked your question too soon. In my view you should delete this question and come back with your SSCCE.

Comment: @pavel.lazar then as i said use debug DCUs and intercept what triggered the destructor

Answer (score 0):

Considering only the code you posted so far, I can´t see the problem. However, since you know the exact location of the error, my advice is to set a breakpoint at that line in code and evaluate (CTRL+F7) the member **FoItems** to see what is it.

Usually, when I suspect I have a bad object reference, I evalute it´s **ClassName**  (in your case, **FoItems.ClassName**). If the reference is invalid, this method usually raises an exception of returns a strange name.

Also, set a breakpoint in the constructor in order to be sure that FoItems is indeed being instantiated.

I Hope this helps!

Comment: `FoItems.ClassName` does not exist since this `FoItems` is an interface. This answer should be a comment.

Comment: The question author said the declaration of FoItems was corrected to be of type TList<IRoutingCode>, so the ClassName method is available.

Comment: Not so. The reported error was when using an interface. The question is confusing and cannot be answered.